# Android testing release build

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, android-testing

I tried to test the release build of the app. So I have added the below config to `build.gradle` of my app. But that didn't make any effect. Test always runs on debug build

```
android {
 compileSdkVersion 24
 buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
  applicationId "com.****.****"
  minSdkVersion 15
  targetSdkVersion 22
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0 Beta"
  testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

testBuildType "release"

signingConfigs {
  release {
    keyAlias '******'
    keyPassword '*****'
    storeFile file('path to keystore')
    storePassword '*****'
  }
}

buildTypes {
  release {
    minifyEnabled true
    debuggable true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
   }
   debug {
     multiDexEnabled true
   }
  }
}
```

When searched for answers in other SO thread I found `testBuildType "release"` will run test on release build but it did not work

Comment: just change your build varient debug to release.

Comment: take a look:  http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Gradle_Build_Variants_Example

Comment: Did you try making changes in the pro-guard files to allow the test packages?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I got it all, but a few things :

- You can test your release with the build variant menu on Android studio (menu at the bottom left) (@Sagar Chavada suggestion)

[image]

- When you generate your signed apk with Android studio you can choose at the end the build type, release in your case
  [image]
- I know it's for testing purpose but `debuggable true` in your realease build won't allow you to push it on Google play

Answer (score -3):

Whenever you are building a project and want to create a signed apk then

Add following code in to android {} in your build.gradle file.

productFlavors {

```
    RELEASE {

        applicationIdSuffix ".release"

        versionNameSuffix "-release"

    }

    DEBUG {

        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

        versionNameSuffix "-debug"

    }

}
```

1. Go to Android SDK --> Build.
2. Tap on Generate Signed APK
3. It will ask to create a debug or Signed build (apk format)
4. Then select release flavour and generate apk.

Comment: I'm aware of the process to generate signed apk. my question is how to run the tests on signed release apk.